# I've installed sonarqube on ec2 instance , and configured python project for code analysis. But the files are scanning continuously

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, sonarqube, devops

```
> INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/ubuntu/sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarScanner 4.6.2.2472
INFO: Java 11.0.11 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 5.4.0-1045-aws amd64
INFO: User cache: /home/ubuntu/.sonar/cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/ubuntu/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 8.6.0
INFO: Default locale: "en", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=694ms
INFO: Server id: DF2851E
INFO: User cache: /home/ubuntu/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=524ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=730ms
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Process project properties (done) | time=20ms
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=7ms
INFO: Project key: my:sampleproj
INFO: Base dir: /home/ubuntu
INFO: Working dir: /home/ubuntu/.scannerwork
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'my:sampleproj'
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=1091ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=11105ms
WARN: SCM provider autodetection failed. Please use "sonar.scm.provider" to define SCM of your project, or disable the SCM Sensor in the project settings.
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO: 30 files indexed
INFO: Quality profile for py: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for web: Sonar way
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module sampleproj
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=582ms
INFO: Sensor Python Sensor [python]
INFO: Starting global symbols computation
INFO: 23 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=856ms
**INFO: 0/23 files analyzed, current file: sampleproj/utils/__init__.py
INFO: 0/23 files analyzed, current file: sampleproj/utils/__init__.py
INFO: 0/23 files analyzed, current file: sampleproj/utils/__init__.py
INFO: 0/23 files analyzed, current file: sampleproj/utils/__init__.py**
```

The last 4 lines 0/23 are continuously repeating for long time , and it is not stopping that soon.Can anyone help me on this issue.
For installing sonarcube i've followed these steps : https://www.coachdevops.com/2021/01/install-sonarqube-8-on-ubuntu-how-to.html
https://sevastoyanov.blogspot.com/2016/09/install-and-configure-sonarqube-for.html

Answer (score 1):

Just answering to my question , I faced this problem because wrong user postgres credentails , I altered the database credentials and tried to run the sonar, boom it's working.